# How to remove blank lines in middle of a string Android

Tags: java, android

```
String Address[] = mSelectedaddress.split("\\|");
address.setText(
                Address[1] + "\n"
                        + Address[2] + "\n"
                        + Address[3] + "\n"
                        + Address[4]);

Actual Output:

Address 1
Address 2
                => Blank line           
City

Wanted Output:

Address 1
Address 2         
City
```

If u can see my above code there are some scenario where `Address[positon]` may return blank text that time how can i remove that line if it is blank.

Comment: you can just check your array entries before setting text to textview if string length is 0 then  append only those entries which has some text to address text

Comment: what is your input format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
String adjusted = adress.replaceAll("(?m)^[ \t]*\r?\n", "");
```

Comment: So simple but worked. @ChrisMoran I'm sure this case "a|b|c|d|e| |g" wont occurs in my code, so i guess it is fine to use this code.

Comment: "a|b|c|d|e| |g" was just an example. The reason you have blank spaces is because there are | with white space between them. This solution won't fix that. Good luck though.

Answer (score 2):

When you build your string, check to see if the string is empty before you add it.

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
for(int it = 0; i < Address.length; i++) {
    if(Address[i] != "")
        builder.append(Address[i]);
    }
    address.setText(builder.toString());
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this code also worked fine buy need some additional work.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest thing I can think of that should do the trick most of the time:

```
mSelectedaddress.replaceAll("[\\|\\s]+", "|").split("\\|");
```

This will remove multiple |'s (with or without spaces) in a row. Those are the cause of your empty lines.

Example:

```
"a|b|c|d|e||g" -> works
"a|b|c|d|e|   |g" -> works
"a|b|c|d|e|||g" -> works
```

Comment: What do you mean it is not what you wanted? It answered the question you asked.